# Adding programatically created views into scrollview vertically (Linear layout in iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I want to add programatically created UIViews into scrollView with auto layout constraints. Like vertical linear layout in Android.
(In objective c not swift)

I have scrollview inside view controller in storyboard. So basically i want to create and add several views in vertical layout with no spaces into that scrollview. And i want to set container size of the scroll view dynamically according to the view heights.

Each view has label inside and each view needs to set its height dynamically according to text size. But probably i need to come to that later.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    UIView *viewOne = UIView.new;
    [viewOne setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"viewOne" : viewOne};
    NSDictionary *metricsDictionary = @{@"horizontalSpacing" : @10};

    [self.scrollview addSubview:viewOne];

    NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-horizontalSpacing-[viewOne]-horizontalSpacing-|"
                                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                             metrics:metricsDictionary
                                                                               views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *const_Height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[viewOne(50)]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];

    [viewOne addConstraints:const_Height];
    [self.scrollview addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
}
```

With that code i can add views but i need to add one under the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of using AutoLayout in the context of a *UIScrollView* I would recommend using a ContentView insider your UIScrollView. Just add them to the ViewControllers View inside the *viewDidLoad* function.

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *dataScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* contentView;
@end

@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize dataScrollView, contentView;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataScrollView  = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    // adding the Views programmatically to the hierarchy
    [self.view addSubview:dataScrollView];
    [dataScrollView addSubview:contentView];

    // don't translate the AutoresizingMask into constraints
    dataScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // backgroundColor as you wish?
    dataScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [dataScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [dataScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];

    NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(dataScrollView, contentView);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[dataScrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[dataScrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [dataScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[contentView(==dataScrollView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [dataScrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

    // see below
    // [self setUpViews];
}
```

This Code will do the Trick for one single view. Add your required Views as Subview to the **contentView** and set the Constraints.

```
- (void) setUpViews {
    UILabel* testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [testLabel setText:@"Lorem Ipsum"];
    testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [contentView addSubview: testLabel];

    // clean up your code with this metrics Dictionary
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"margintop": @40,
                          @"marginleft": @10,
                          @"marginright": @10,
                          @"marginbottom": @20}

    // the Views we want to layout with Constraints
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{
                                  @"contentView":contentView,
                                  @"dataScrollView":dataScrollView,
                                  @"testLabel": testLabel}

    // Horizontal (testlabel)
    [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-marginleft-[testLabel]-marginright-|" options:0 metrics: metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
    // Vertical
    [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-margintop-[testLabel]-marginbottom-|" options:0 metrics: metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
}
```

Referring to your question of adding multiple Views in a for-loop, there are a lot of possible ways. This could be the easiest solution with *constraintsWithVisualFormat*.

```
- (void) setUpViews {
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"margintop": @40,
                          @"marginleft": @10,
                          @"marginright": @10,
                          @"marginbottom": @20,
                          };
    // Alsways like to have contentView and DataScrollView here
    NSMutableDictionary* dictViews = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"contentView":contentView,
                                                                                   @"dataScrollView":dataScrollView}];

    // Basic Leading-String for Vertical Constraints
    NSString* verticalConstraintsString = @"V:|-margintop-";
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        // Do your Magic here & add your View
        UILabel* testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [testLabel setText:@"Lorem Ipsum"];
        testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [contentView addSubview: testLabel];

        // Add to global Mutable Views-Dictionary dictViews
        [dictViews setObject:testLabel forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testLabel%lu", (unsigned long)index]];
        // add "[testlabel1]" to the vertical Constraints
        verticalConstraintsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[testLabel%lu]-", verticalConstraintsString, (unsigned long)index];
        // Add Horizontal Constraints
        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-marginleft-[testLabel%lu]-marginright-|", (unsigned long)index] options:0 metrics: metrics views:@{@"testLabel-%lu":testLabel}]];
    }

    // Trailing-String
    verticalConstraintsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@marginbottom-|", verticalConstraintsString];
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictViews];

    // finally adding the vertical Constraints
    [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraintsString options:0 metrics: metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
}
```

I hope this will help you to get your Views right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped alot. But i also want to create these views in the loop. So how can i set constraints with each other? 

In your example how can i create testLabel in the loop. With this code it will add each testLabel on top of the old one. Because all of them has same constraint to top layout.

Comment: I have updated my answer and tried to solve your Problem.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem. I changed testLabel-%lu to testLabel%lu. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: you should have also given solution for setting content size of scroll view

Comment: @MithunR. I'm not sure If I'm misunderstanding your comment, but the contentSize property of UIScrollViews should not be relevant for this solution. The size of the scrollview-content is automatically defined by the size of my "contentView" object. The size of the "contentView" object then again is set by the size of it's containing Views. Please rectify my thoughts on this :)

Comment: I get this error from the second example: testLabel0 is not a key in the views dictionary.