# Reorganise a screen in objective-c after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an iPhone application, and in one view I am planning to have a split screen. It will be a map view in the main area of the page, but I want to then display a table underneath the map that shows details of the nearest hits to the user.

So the layout in portrait view will be like this:

```
------------
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
------------
|          |
|          |
|          |
------------
```

With a 60/40 split between the top mapview area and the bottom table area.

When I rotate the phone, I need this layout to re-adjust and rotate sensibly, so that it adjusts to:

```
---------------------------
|               |         |
|               |         |
|               |         |
|               |         |
|               |         |
|               |         |
|               |         |
|               |         |
---------------------------
```

With the mapview in the left area and the table at the right.

And, of course, re-layout between the two views smoothly as the user rotates their device.

What is the best way to handle this in code? I am not sure what is the best way to re-layout the screen on rotation?

Is it good practice to just resize and move the two views using, eg for the top view:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight*0.6)];
```

And then use the following to move and redraw this when I detect an orientation change:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth*0.6, screenHeight)];
```

Comment: Best practice would be to use `AutoLayout` but your approach should do the trick too.

Comment: Why don't you use two views? http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/window-uiviewcontroller-etc/orientation/designing-separate-views-for-landscape-and-portrait

Comment: @Jasper, the _Auto-Layout_ is definitely not capable of doing such layout reorganisation.

Comment: @holex not even with size-classes?

Comment: @Jasper, the issue is that the _Auto-Layout_ does not change the dependency between the views; like a _trailing-space_ will be never converted to a _bottom-space_ or vica-verse, not even with size-classes. if a view defines a constraint in `xib` as _trailing-space_ to a sibling view, that will be always a _trailing-space_ to that sibling and the dependency of the constraint always will be the same [currently], no matter how desperately you'd rotate the device.

Comment: @holex I know you can set different frames and constraints for different size-classes, so in theory it should work with auto-layout. To stay on-topic: his approach should do the trick :)

Comment: @Jasper, the point is (w/ or w/o size-classes) the dependency (or hierarchy, if you like it) won't be updated. like e.g. if two items side-siblings and they are next to each other they will be forever like this, because _Auto-layout_ won't change that, it might change their size or frame, but they will be side-siblings forever, they will never be top-bottom neighbours – until manually the layout is updated, but the point is the _Auto-layout_ won't do that job for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the exact same behaviour by using Autolayout with multiple Arrays of Constraints. Just save yourself a reference of the applied *NSLayoutConstraint*'s. Lets Assume you have declared your Views as a property and synthesized them like listed below.

```
@interface YourFancySplitScreenViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) AwesomeMapView* myAwesomeMapView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CoolTableView* myCoolTableView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* portraitLayoutConstraints;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* landscapeLayoutConstraint;
@end

@implementation YourFancySplitScreenViewController
@synthesize myAwesomeMapView, myCoolTableView;
@synthesize portraitLayoutConstraints, landscapeLayoutConstraint;

// [...]

@end
```

Just set up your Views and add them as Subviews to *UIViewController.view*. After this you fill up your Arrays **portraitLayoutConstraints** and **landscapeLayoutConstraint** with the appropriate Constraints.

```
- (void) getYourConstraintsRight {
    // The Views you want to manipulate with your Constraints
    NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myAwesomeMapView, myCoolTableView);

    self.portraitLayoutConstraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.landscapeLayoutConstraint = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Now just add The Constraints to your Arrays, eg. with constraintsWithVisualFormat
    [self.portraitLayoutConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"Your terrific portrait Contstraints" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [self.landscapeLayoutConstraint addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"Your even better landscape Contstraints" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];

}
```

In my current Project I add the **portraitLayoutConstraints** to the view. After this I deactivate the Constraints from the same Array. Afterwards I can add the **landscapeLayoutConstraint** and deactivate them as well. This is for sure not the most elegant way of implement the intended behaviour, but it does the trick for me. Having my Constraints set, I can deactivate and activate them, as I need them.

```
- (void) addYourConstraintsToTheView {
    // place some ugly code here
    [self.view addConstraints:self.landscapeLayoutConstraint];
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.landscapeLayoutConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraints:self.portraitLayoutConstraints];
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.portraitLayoutConstraints];
}

- (void) setYourConstraintsAccordingToTheUIInterfaceOrientation {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.landscapeLayoutConstraint];
    }
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.portraitLayoutConstraints];
    }
}
```

In my special Case I wanted to react to the change of the DeviceOrientation, so I added an Observer for *UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification* in my *viewDidLoad* and deactivate/activate the Constraints when the DeviceOrientation changes.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Maybe you want to set your views here
    // then add the Constraints
    [self getYourConstraintsRight];
    [self addYourConstraintsToTheView];
    [self setYourConstraintsAccordingToTheUIInterfaceOrientation];

    // Observe your Notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notification_OrientationWillChange:) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)notification_OrientationWillChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self animateToPortrait];
    }
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self animateToLandscape];
    }
}

- (void)animateToPortrait {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints: self.landscapeLayoutConstraint];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints: self.portraitLayoutConstraints];
    }];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)animateToLandscape {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints: self.portraitLayoutConstraints];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints: self.landscapeLayoutConstraint];
    }];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

// You want to remove the Observer
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisapper:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.view];
}
```

Maybe this will help to find a solution for your Problem. Another difficulty I see in the available indicating range in Portrait Orientation. If you consider to hug the content inside a scrollview check out this answer of mine: [Adding programatically created views into scrollview vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194928/5075041). Also I would recommend the WWDC2015 Session on [Mysteries of Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218) and the corresponding [AstroLayout Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AstroLayout/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want your UI to adapt.  [Apple wants your UI to adapt.](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/)

You could write the code to handle orientation changes and lay the views out yourself, but you might miss an edge case, or it might not work on a future device or with upcoming functionality (such as split-screen multitasking).

Instead of trying to write code to handle this yourself, you may want to take advantage of [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/).

> Stack views let you leverage the power of Auto Layout, creating user interfaces **that can dynamically adapt to the device’s orientation**, screen size, and any changes in the available space.

Comment: UIStackView is an iOS 9 SDK feature.

Comment: Yes, it is.  But the point is that *the SDK already will handle all the cases*, including switching back to vertical orientation if the app is displayed in a compact multi-tasking view.  No need to write code.